# Should NSZombieEnabled be turned off for released app or not?

Tags: ios, memory-management, release, nszombieenabled

With `NSZombieEnabled` turned on it will provide some guard against the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` issues happening at runtime.

I am doing dual-diligence to make sure no/little memory leaks, but I might over releasing so having `NSZombieEnabled` turned on would help prevent that, am I right? Or with `NSZombieEnabled` turned on, would all memory releasing operations be translated into no-op? It'll be a big problem is that's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should not ship with `NSZombiesEnable`.  Zombies work by casting the isa pointer of deallocated objects to a "zombie" class.  The storage for this object is not freed unless `NSDeallocateZombies` is enabled.  Therefore, if you leave zombies enabled, you may be leaking memory.

In addition, Apple says not to leave it enabled in `NSDebug.h`:

> Do not depend on the existance of any of these symbols in your code
>   in future releases of this software.  Certainly, do not depend on the
>   symbols in this header in production code.

If distributing on the AppStore, my guess is that you would not pass the review.

Answer (score 1):

You should turn it off because having the NSZombieEnabled on means the objects you allocated are not deallocated, hence your app will be leaking.

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled

''NSZombieEnabled should not be left in place permanently, as by default no objects will ever be truly deallocated, making your application use tremendous amounts of memory''