# NSZombieEnabled: Can it cause an app to crash

Tags: objective-c, nszombieenabled

If you deploy with NSZombieEnabled could it have adverse affects on your app?

Answer (score 0):

### IF you could set it:

yes it will crash for sure ;) you'd keep on using more and more RAM (I give it a minute or two ;))

### But you can't:

as it is a program argument

Comment: Thanks - so even if your developing and you have it set, when you build an ipa it won't be included? It seems this SO post indicates you can release with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647432/should-nszombieenabled-be-turned-off-for-released-app-or-not?rq=1